# Ionic Pro Error: more than one library with package name ‘com.google.android.gms.license’

Tags: android, ionic-framework

With the change today that broke with the error: "more than one library with package name ‘com.google.android.gms.license’", I did manage to fix it by changing the version for com.google.firebase:firebase records in the platforms project.properties file.  But, since I'm building with Ionic Pro, these changes will not work there.  Is there a way to fix this problem that holds without changing a file in the platforms folder?

Comment: The `com.google.android.gms.license` libraries were introduced in Google Play services 12.0.0 - do you see the same error when you use `11.8.0`?

Comment: I changed com.google.firebase:firebase-core and com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging to 11.+ in the project.properties file under platforms/android.  That does fix the issue when building locally.  But, since that is a modification in the platforms folder, it will not work for a Ionic Pro build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing this error with the 12.0.0 version, it was fixed in the latest 12.0.1 version: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#march_28_2018_-_version_1201